# How can I intercept a function from glibc and print the values of its parameters?

Tags: c, glibc

In glibc, the function _IO_new_fopen() is called by the fopen() libcall. If I am running the following code, is there any approach that allows me to intercept the _IO_new_fopen() function whenever it gets called and printout the values of its parameters?

For kernel functions, this can be achieved by Jprobe, and I am actually looking for a similar mechanism for the functions in glibc. LD_PRELOAD is a related mechnism in glibc that allows us to replace a glibc function with our self-defined function, but it does not help to achieve my goal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main(void){

    char buff[100];
    int i, r1;
    FILE *f1 = fopen("text.txt", "wb");

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            buff[i] = 'b';
    }
    assert(f1);
    r1 = fwrite(buff, 1, 100, f1);
    printf("wrote %d elements\n", r1);
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `glibc`, `fopen` is a [public] symbol *alias* to [local symbol] `_IO_new_fopen` (i.e. they are identical), so, technically speaking, `fopen` doesn't *call* `_IO_new_fopen`--it *is* it.

If you are interested in intercepting the call as shown in your example (i.e. from the *app*), then using `LD_PRELOAD` [along with `dlopen`, `dlsym`, etc.] and defining your own `fopen` *will* work. I've done this before in my own code.

You may just be missing an entry point (i.e. you may need to define/intercept multiple symbols): `fopen`, `fopen64`, `_IO_file_fopen`, `_IO_fopen`, etc. If you do `readelf -s` on your executable, the simple `fopen` may show up as something else. I'm guessing that you'll see `fopen64`. Also, you may need to account for symbol versioning.

You won't be able to intercept *internal* calls within `glibc` to `fopen` because they bypass the mechanism and go direct. But, this isn't quite so useful, so more details on your part might be required.

You can also look at `fopencookie` as a way to intercept the underlying `read(2)`, `write(2)`, etc. syscalls.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Specifically, I am trying to print the address and the content of the buffer that is used by fread()/fwrite().

Easy to do. Details below ...

> I think it should be able to be done by adding "printk()" somewhere and rebuild libc.so.6, but is there any approach that is more convenient (i.e. without rebuilding libc.so.6)?

No need to rebuild `libc`, the `LD_PRELOAD` will handle it. Remember that `printk` is in the *kernel*. No need to go there [and it probably wouldn't work]

The address you want is what's passed to `fread` and *not* the buffer that's passed to `read(2)`. The buffer passed to `read(2)` is within the `FILE` struct, so, it wouldn't tell you much. Otherwise, you could just run the whole program under `strace(1)` [or write your own custom version that uses `ptrace(2)`].

You can intercept, trace, breakpoint on, etc. an arbitrary number of functions. You just need to create your own shared library (`.so`) and set `LD_PRELOAD` to it.

Here is a sample interceptor function [for `fread`]:

```
// trapme -- put gdb breakpoint on this function
__attribute__((__noinline__)) void
trapme(void)
{

    // prevent the function call to this from being optimized away
    __asm__ __volatile__ () ::: memory;
}

// dumpme -- dump out a buffer
void
dumpme(const void *buf,size_t xlen)
{

    // dump data in whatever format you'd like ...
}

// fread -- intercept fread calls
size_t
fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    static size_t
    (*fread_real)(void *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,FILE *stream) = NULL;
    size_t xlen;

    printf("fread_fake: ENTER ptr=%p size=%lX nmemb=%ld stream=%p\n",
        ptr,size,nmemb,stream);

    // do trap on some suspicious activity ...
#if 0
    if (ptr == ...)
        trapme();
#endif

    // locate the real symbol in glibc
    if (fread_real == NULL)
        fread_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fread");
    // abort if fread_real is still null ...

    xlen = fread_real(ptr,size,nmemb,stream);

    // dump out the data
    if (xlen > 0)
        dumpme(ptr,xlen * size);

    // do trap on some suspicious activity ...
#if 0
    if (xlen == 372)
        trapme();
#endif

    printf("fread_fake: EXIT xlen=%ld\n",xlen);

    return xlen;
}
```

That's the basic mechanism. You can add whatever [nefarious] things you desire. You can get fancy and add some logic that traps if a buffer is in some [bad] range or funny buffer contents. That is, similar to a `cond` statement for a `gdb` breakpoint. So, you can use this to trigger and drop into `gdb` using much more complex tests than you could with `gdb` alone [to find really hard to find bugs].

You can also monitor the `fopen` and remember the filename, etc.

Getting this mechanism working isn't *too* difficult, but my suggestion would be to write the interceptor for `fopen` and get familiar with the `dlsym` trick first (vs. trying to debug it within a loop).

You can create as many of these functions as you need. Start simply (e.g. `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`). Then, add more as you find a "gap" in the coverage (e.g. Eventually, you'll probably find that intercepting `fseek` gives you needed information)

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Here is a sample `strace` script with the options that I like to use:

```
strace -ttt -i -f -etrace=all -o \
    /home/me/log/foobar.spysys \
    -eread=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 \
    -ewrite=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 \
    -x foobar
```

The `-eread` and `-ewrite` can be extended to as many units as you need

Comment: Thanks! Specifically, I am trying to print the address and the content of the buffer that is used by fread()/fwrite(). I think it should be able to be done by adding "printk()" somewhere and rebuild libc.so.6, but is there any approach that is more convenient (i.e. without rebuilding libc.so.6)?

Comment: Thanks! But what I wanna print out is the address and the content of the internal buffer allocated by fwrite(). For example, fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) will write the data in the buffer pointed by "ptr" to some buffer that allocated internally by the fwrite() library call. The internal buffer is related with the "stream". Then, the data in that internal buffer will be wriiten to disk by fflush() or fsync(). So I am actually  interested in the internal buffer, but not the buffer pointed by ptr.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, if that's all you want [the internal buffer], you can do this with `strace(1)` as that's what will be passed to the `write(2)` syscall, which `strace` can dump out easily (i.e. just a few command line options to `strace [options] mypgm`

Comment: I see, will try strace. Thanks! @Craig Estey