# how to get null when allocating memory with malloc

Tags: c, testing, null, malloc

Body:
I am working on a C codebase, and I need to write a test case to handle the scenario where malloc returns NULL in the s21_create_matrix function. Below is the relevant portion of the code:

```
int s21_create_matrix(int rows, int columns, matrix_t *result) {
  int status = S21_OK;

  if (result == NULL || rows < 0 || columns < 0) {
    result->rows = 0;
    result->columns = 0;
    result->matrix = NULL;
    return S21_INCORRECT_MATRIX;
  }

  if (status == S21_OK) {
    result->matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * rows);
    if (result->matrix == NULL) { // We need to check this case
      result->rows = 0;
      result->columns = 0;
      result->matrix = NULL;
      status = S21_INCORRECT_MATRIX;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows && status == S21_OK; ++i) {
    result->matrix[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * columns);
    if (result->matrix[i] == NULL) {
      status = S21_INCORRECT_MATRIX;
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        free(result->matrix[j]);
      }
      free(result->matrix);
    }
  }

  if (status == S21_OK) {
    result->columns = columns;
    result->rows = rows;
  }

  return status;
}
```

I attempted to create a test to cover the case where malloc returns NULL. I replaced malloc with a simple mock function:

```
void *mock_malloc(size_t size) {
    (void)size;
    return NULL;
}
```

I wrote an orientation test, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to override malloc for a while?

However, my test is not working as expected. Is there a proper way to temporarily override malloc for the duration of the test?

Thank you for your assistance!

Due to my little experience, I have tried searching the internet and asking ChatGPT, but so far I have not been able to find an answer anywhere.

```
// Test for checking error with malloc
START_TEST(create_matrix_malloc_failure) {
    // Replace malloc with mock_malloc
    malloc = mock_malloc;

    matrix_t matrix;
    int status = s21_create_matrix(3, 4, &matrix);

    // Restore the original malloc function
    malloc = original_malloc;

    ck_assert_int_eq(status, S21_INCORRECT_MATRIX);
    ck_assert_int_eq(0, matrix.rows);
    ck_assert_int_eq(0, matrix.columns);
    ck_assert_ptr_null(matrix.matrix);
}
END_TEST
```

Comment: Linux?  Disable memory overcommit and the OOM killer then call `malloc()` with a large enough value that your system can't handle it.

Comment: You cannot just override `malloc`, because your override routine needs to provide allocated memory (in those cases where it is not returning a null pointer). You could write your own memory management for that, or your override could call the library `malloc`. Inserting a routine to handle calls to an original routine but then call the original routine is called “interposition.” Searching Stack Overflow and other sources for “interpose”, ”interposing”, and/or “interposition” will give you information on that.

Comment: However, you described the problem as “it doesn't work.” That is not an adequate problem description and should never be used as a problem description. You should explain what happened, what you want to happen instead, and show a complete example, as a [mre].

Comment: I've used CMock (http://www.throwtheswitch.org/cmock), but setting it up for unit testing is not trivial. Basically you have to commit to it for a framework. Otherwise you have to put your mocks in a separate file from your actual functions, and swap the files when running tests. If you can't tell the compiler to not use a built-in version of a function you might have to wrap the function (e.g. `mockable_malloc()`) so you can make a mock version. I think `malloc()` is a function you can replace with your own allocator though.

Comment: You can create a wrapper for `malloc` calls and put into a shared library, then use `LD_PRELOAD` to force that on the target program (which needs no changes). See my answer: [How can I intercept a function from glibc and print the values of its parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893440/5382650) There, it's `fread` but similar for `malloc`. In _your_ `malloc`, you could do: `if (malloc_fake_null) return NULL;` and have the program set that global appropriately. You could also just link directly with the `.o` for the lib (if that's easier).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code isn't working is because you are checking to see if a pointer is NULL, then immediately dereferencing it. You cannot dereference a NULL pointer.